# how to recover the string used to generate the given hash?

Tags: python, string, hash, passwords, sha256

The code:

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.sha256("user,12345,999999".encode()).hexdigest())
```

is used to generate a hash:

```
c50603be4fedef7a260ef9181a605c27d44fe0f37b3a8c7e8dbe63b9515b8e96
```

However, I'm not sure how I could recover the password from this hash? I understand that it's first converted into bytes and then returned into hexadecimals. However, if someone gave me a random hash and I had to find the string from it, I would not know how to backtrack it.

Comment: You're using `sha256`, you won't be getting the plaintext string from the hash. [How much would it cost to crack sha-256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year/1160#1160)

Comment: @PacketLoss but if someone were to ask me to find the "12345" part of the string using the hash, how would i even recover that?

Comment: There is no physical way to break a 256-bit hash. You are not recovering any part of any string from the hash alone. You can say, try hash strings until you match the hash, but you cannot reverse the hash into a string.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a hash is that it only goes one way. You can't "undo" it.

If you have a hash and you want to find the string that was hashed, you have 3 options:

1. Find a supercomputer and launch an attack. It may take days, decades, millennia, or finish after the universe has ended (depending on the hash function).
2. Randomly guess strings, hash them, and see if they match.
3. Lookup in a rainbow table: https://crackstation.net/

Comment: I had tried option 3 as it is sha256, however nothing was found. If I used the same process with a different string and had to find a section of the string with the given hash, would it not be possible at all? Not even with an algorithm?

Comment: If Crackstation doesn't have it, they don't have it. The algorithms for hashing functions are specifically designed so you can't create an algorithm to go backwards.